# Stored procedure does not return any documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a very simple stored procedure in my cosmos database. Currently, I'm just querying a document based on it's Id, as follows:

```
    function sample(id) {
        var context = getContext();
        var collection = context.getCollection();
        var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
        var response = context.getResponse();
        executeQuery();

        function executeQuery() {
            var query = "select * from groups c where c.id = "+ id
            var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, {}, function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
                if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
                if (documents.length > 0) {
                    console.log("found")
                }
                else {
                    console.log("nothing")
                }
            })
        }


    }
```

For some reason, the above procedure does not return any documents. I Am unsure what's missing above. I have double-checked that the `id` exists.

Also, I'm just executing the procedure in the portal - It tells me to specify a partitionkey - But typing in id does not affect anything (Id is my partitionkey)

Comment: When executing the stored procedure, you will need to specify the value of partition key attribute (i.e. value of `Id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly noted here in the official MS doc: [How to run stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#:%7E:text=as%20spCreateToDoItem.js.-,Note,-For%20partitioned%20containers)

> For partitioned containers, when executing a stored procedure, a
> partition key value must be provided in the request options. Stored
> procedures are always scoped to a partition key. Items that have a
> different partition key value will not be visible to the stored
> procedure.

Checkout this example:

[image]

where **MyidValue** will be **Hyderabad** if you consider below example item with Partition key as **/city**.

[image]

Since you have **id** as a Partition key, you can specify  **MyidValue** as **1** in reference to the above example.

**Note:** Because stored procedure is scoped to a logic partition. If you have more than one logic partition, only 1 item will be accessible.

For more details follow: [How to write stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#stored-procedures), [How to run stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#stored-procedures)